# How shall we show that the only possible orders of any element in dihedral group $D_n$ will be either a divisor of 2 or $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I am studying the dihedral group $D_n:=\{r_n, f_n: r_n^n=f_n^2=(r_nf_n)^2=e_n\}$.

I am willing to show that the possible orders of any element in it will be either a divisor of 2 or $n$. But don't know how shall I show it.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Every element in $D_n$ can be written as $f^i r^k$ for some $i\in\{0,1\}$ and $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, so it is either of the form $r^k$ or $fr^k$. Can you figure which orders are possible for elements $r^k$, and what the order of $fr^k$ can be?

Comment: ohh nice! I got it. Thank you so much for your reply. Its clear to me now'

Comment: I could write my comment as an answer. But if you think you have the solution, you could even write an answer to your own question here. This is encouraged by this platform.

Comment: Alright sir. I am writing my thought. Please comment if I make any mistake

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefan Hamcke suggested, this is what I got.

Any element in $D_n$ is of the form $r^k$ or $r^kf$ where $k\in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1\}$. NOte that $D_n$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ which is generated by $r$ viz $\langle r\rangle=C_n\leq D_n$ and we know that for every divisor $d$ of $n$ the cyclic group $\langle r\rangle$ will contain a cyclic subgroup of order $d$.

On the other hand, any element of the form $r^kf$ will have order 2 because using the relation $(rf)^2=1$ i.e. $rf=fr^{-1}$ one see that $(r^kf)^2=r^kfr^kf=r^kr^{-k}ff=e$

hence any element of $D_n$ will have possible order as divisor of $2$ or $n$.

Did I make any mistake ?

Comment: I think you meant $r^k f r^k f = r^kr^{-k}ff = E$. And for $r^k$ we actually use the property that its order divides $n$ since $r^k\in\langle r\rangle$, which has order $n$. Otherwise, it's good.

Comment: opps!! exactly sir, thank you , yes thats what i tried to say

Comment: The first paragraph is still not quite proper. You should not use that for every divisor $d$ of $n$ there is a subgroup of order $d$ (which is correct nevertheless), but rather the converse, namely that for every subgroup there is a divisor $d$ of $n$ such that the order of the subgroup is $d$ (this holds for all finite groups, not just the cyclic ones). Maybe that is what you had in mind, but then the formulation is not quite right.

Comment: can you please edit the mistake of mine you are referring ? @StefanHamcke

Comment: I feel that's not the proper way to learn the theory. Do you understand what I meant? If yes, then you should edit it yourself. But if you are not sure, feel free to ask.

Comment: Alright. According to my knowledge, we are considering the cyclic subgroup of order $n$ and its subgroup. Since these subgroups are also cyclic and unique so I thought I have written the correct phrase. However after getting your suggestion, I am actually confused exactly which part did I miss. This is why I am unable to edit. :-(

Comment: Oh. Well you have an element of the form $s=r^k$, which is an element of $\langle r\rangle$. You want to show that its order is a divisor of $n$. Now $⟨s⟩$ is a subgroup of $⟨r⟩$, so its order (which is the order of $s$) is a divisor of $n$, by Lagrange's theorem (do you know that theorem?). And that's what we want to show.

Comment: While what you wrote is correct, this only implies that given a divisor $d$ of $n$, there is a $g\in⟨r⟩$ such that $⟨g⟩=d$. However, this does not mean there could not also be an $h\in⟨r⟩$ whose order is not a divisor of $n$.